# Sourcetree: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally

Tags: git

Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
(e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Yes, I know but that's the point of pushing. I have deleted some files on local branch and need them to be deleted on the remote as well.
What's the best way to do so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do+not+have+locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1(gentle way to do it)

1. You can call `git pull --rebase` before you do `git push`
2. If `git pull` can't merge cleanly, you need to fix the conflicts between local and remote repository.
3. After you fix the conflict and sync the repo, it will be possible to `git push` cleanly.

Solution 2(brute way to do it)

1. If you don't care about the difference(e.g. you own the repository and it's only used by yourself), you can do `git push --force` to overwrite the remote repository.
2. After you overwrite the remote repository, `git pull` from another local repo will break, you can use `git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master` to force sync it.

Comment: Thanks so much! First solution did the trick. I didn't even hear about rebase until now

Comment: You might want to take a look at all subcommands supported by git: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/git.1.html
No need to master them or know the details, just get familiar with basic concepts and operations.

Answer (score 0):

1. stash or commit your changes
2. Take a pull
3. if conflicts are found resolve the same
4. push your changes